# Twilio Queue Dial no parent-child Relation

Tags: twilio

I am enqueueing inbound calls to a queue, and my client queries queue counts, if there is an item in the queue, client calls the queue, the result is Agent (TwilioJS) is connected to the first call in the queue. Works well, I can get the relation between these two calls with the dequeue hook, and I know the relation between the Agent-Inbound call.

But I don't have the inbound CallSid in the client, so I am unable to get the connected queue items (inbound callers phone number) from the client.

I tried fetching, reading call resources, checked Twilio logs, but there is no parent-child relation or any kind of relation between two legs.

Isn't there a way other than updating the DB with dequeue hook, and querying the backend to get the parent (inbound call) with the Client CallSid.

Thanks

Enqueue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
<Say>You are now connecting to an agent</Say>
<Enqueue action="{...}/EnqueueHook">QueueName</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Call Queue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial record="record-from-answer" recordingStatusCallback="{...}/RecordingStatusHook">
    <Queue url="{...}/DequeueHook?client=adnanturken" method="POST">QueueName</Queue>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a good point, it's hard to get detail to the client side on this. Your workaround might be a good idea.

One thing that did occur to me is that when you make the request to find the size of the queue, before you return the result, query the queue for the top call and return the details back to the client at that point.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks, I get the relation on dequeuehook, store it in db, when agent connects to call frontend queries the db gets the relation. I think there is no other way to solve this. I think getting the top call isn't a good idea since there will be multiple frontends getting calls from that queue.